# Comando Exec no hace nada en PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, php5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
echo "Hola mundo.";
exec ("uname -a");
exec ("echo uname -a");
?>
```

el comando exec no hace nada en las dos líneas.

Soy *newbie* en php y estoy atascado.

SO Lubuntu **18.04**

xampp **5.6.30**

PHP Version **5.6.23** (*Según PHPInfo*)

---

Si me sugieren que revise el php.ini, me pueden decir cual de los php.ini que tengo es el que tengo que ver:

```
root@Lubuntu18:/home/rafael# find / -name php.ini -print
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
root@Lubuntu18:/home/rafael# find / -name php.ini-development -print
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-development
root@Lubuntu18:/home/rafael# find / -name php.ini-production -print
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production
root@Lubuntu18:/home/rafael#
```

Si me sugieren que quite el **exec** del ***disable_functions***, el disable_options solo tiene esta opción *pcntl_exec*, lo he quitado y puesto y nada. En ninguna parte sale el *exec*.

Alguna idea que complemente lo que he intentado o algo diferente???

**Actualización**:

Investigando un poco mas confirmé que el php.ini que lee es el

`/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`

y tiene estos parámetros que pueden ser de interés:

```
disable_functions=
safe_mode=Off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`exec()`](http://php.net/function.exec) devuelve la última línea devuelta por la ejecución en forma de cadena:

> string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
>
> #### Parámetros
>
> `command`: El comando que será ejecutado.
>
> `output`: Si el argumento `output` está presente, entonces el array especificado será llenado con cada línea de la salida del comando [...]
>
> `return_var`: Si el argumento `return_var` está presente junto con el argumento output, entonces el status de retorno del comando ejecutado será escrito en esta variable.
>
> ### Valores devueltos
>
> La última línea de los resultados del comando. Si necesita ejecutar un comando y tener todos los datos desde el comando pasados directamente de vuelta sin interferencia alguna, use la función `passthru()`.
>
> Para obtener la salida del comando ejecutado, asegúrese de definir y usar el parámetro `output`.

Al no enviar nada al navegador hay que usar explícitamente alguna función que envíe la información, como [`echo`](http://php.net/echo):

```
<?php
echo "Hola mundo.";
echo exec("uname -a");
echo exec("echo uname -a");
```

Una forma alternativa que muestra toda la salida (y no únicamente la última línea) de manera directa en el navegador sería haciendo uso de [`passthru()`](http://php.net/passthru):

```
<?php
echo "Hola mundo.";
passthru("uname -a");
passthru("echo uname -a");
```

El problema es que no controlas la salida para poder convertirla en HTML de manera segura.

Si quieres almacenar el resultado completo de la salida para poder tratarlo como HTML mediante [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), entonces debes usar [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec):

```
<?php
echo "Hola mundo.";
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(shell_exec("uname -a")), '</pre>', PHP_EOL;
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(shell_exec("echo uname -a")), '</pre>', PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

el php.ini que debes revisar en tu caso es

```
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: Amigo sigo sin resolver el problema del exec, leyendo un poco mas pude averiguar y confirmar que el php.ini que lee xampp es  el: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Comment: ok deberías haber empezado por eso, estas usando windows ?

Comment: SO Lubuntu  18.04